# Position of points in a QGIS vector layer

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have created a new layer overlaying a map, then chosen the "add feature" tool to add points, which I have named with numbers, representing the location of customers.
I need to have the coordinate positions of my points. Where do I find them? I have tried Layer-Open attribute table but this only contains my number-names for my points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate the coordinates, if you want to add them to the attribute table. Otherwise you can use the identify tool to see the coordinates of a single point.

Comment: How do I calculate the coordinates?

Comment: you open the attribute table, start editing, open the calculator. there you check new field, specify the names and types of the columns and enter the formula to calculate the coordinates. For example to fill a column with the x-Values you insert  $x

Comment: its a basic GIS Task - you will find a lot of detailed explanations...

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Identity** tool to see point's coordinates.

[image]

- Select the tool. When you click a point you will see attributes of the point also extra information under **Derived** section in **Identity Results** panel.

[image]

**OR**

You can add points' coordinates to attribute table using **Field Calculator**.

[image]

- Click **Field Calculator** button. A window shows up. In that window, create new field as shown in following image. Use `$x` for X coordinate, `$y` for Y coordinate, seperately.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]